# Please mention some CFD resources

Tags: c++, 3d, mesh

I am working as c++ developer in cfd field for last 1.5 years. Since I am from computer science background I have very poor domain knowledge in CFD. I have searched on net but didn't get the kind of material am looking for. Actually am getting mathematical research papers about cfd focusing on theory and formulas . What I want is a tutorial written in plain English targeting novice people with focus on software development. I might be asking too much , but any help is appreciable :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you want to have a somewhat more friendly introduction (although you simply won't be able to escape math) you might start at "Fluid Flow for the Rest of Us" by Cline, Cardon and Egbert and work your way up from there. Google it and you'll find it online.

Or you could have a look at Robert Bridson's book "[Fluid Simulation for Computer Graphics](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/fluidbook/)" which introduces the basic concepts in a more gentle way.

These are both texts dealing with fluids targeted at computer graphics, but they might provide a gentle introduction while you work your way up to CFD simulations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a quick response. Will definitely check it out

Answer (score 3):

I've worked with/on two C++ libraries that both come with a lot of theory, docs and tutorials:  http://www.dealii.org/ and http://libmesh.sourceforge.net/. Both are adaptive refinement finite element libraries, both with a focus on (scientific) fluid simulations.

Comment: Simply just what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Another good start could be [Fast Fluid Dynamics Simulation on the GPU](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch38.html), which actually lends to a very simple (but not optimal) implementation on the CPU.

It comes with shader's source that can be ported straight to the CPU, and provides an easier and more programming oriented approach than Bridson's book.

Comment: I love GPUGems and have based my simulations on their paper, but this one is quite nice too, I have to give it a try as well https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00596050/document, by the way the link you posted is broken, here is the updated link: https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems/gpugems_ch38.html